# Cant get referenced object attributes to console.log()

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am having trouble getting referenced data to log from within another object.

I currently have two models...

var mongoose = require("mongoose");

STUDENT:

```
var gameSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        name: String,
        courses:   [
            {
                type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                ref:  "Course"
            }
        ]
    });

module.exports = mongoose.model("Student", gameSchema);
```

COURSES:

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");

var courseSchema = new mongoose.Schema (
    {
        name: String,
        student: [
            {
                id: 
                {
                    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                    ref: "Student"
                },
                name: String
            }
        ]
    }
);

module.exports = mongoose.model("Course", courseSchema);
```

When I console.log(foundStudent.courses[0].name) I get undefined and I can't figure out why...

```
app.post("/students/:id", function(req, res){
   Student.findById(req.params.id, function(err, foundStudent){
       if(err){
           console.log(err);
       } else {
          Course.create(req.body.class, function(err, createdCourse){
              if(err){
                  console.log(err);
              } else {

                    createdCourse.student.push(foundStudent);
                    createdCourse.save();

                    foundStudent.courses.push(createdCourse);
                    foundStudent.save();
                    res.redirect("/students/" + req.params.id);
              }
          });
       }
   });
});
```

Here is the show page...

```
<div>
    <h1>Student Profile</h1>
    <h2>Name: <%=student.name%></h2>
    <div>
        <h3>Classes:
            <form action="/students/<%= student._id %>" method="POST">
                <% student.courses.forEach(function(course){ %>
                    <li><p><%= course.name %></p></li>
                <% }); %>
            <a href="/students/<%=student._id%>/courses/new">Add Course</a>
            </form>
        </h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You have to use [populate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) to get referenced objects automatically.

Comment: And this should go in the get route yes?

Comment: Yes, after any find method that returns a `DocumentQuery` object. This means that the callback has to be moved to the `exec` method of the DocumentQuery object, eg: `Student.findById(id).populate('courses').exec((err, res) => ...)`.

Comment: Sadly this is still keeping just the id and not the values within my Student object. `app.get("/students/:id", function(req, res){
    Student.findById(req.params.id).populate("courses").exec(function(err, foundStudent){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log(foundStudent);
            res.render("students/show", {student: foundStudent});
        }
    });
});`

Comment: I have added an example as an answer to your thread. It takes up too many characters to explain how to use populate properly in a SO comment.

Answer (score 0):

I have added a simple test suite using `mockgoose` and `mocha` to present the usage of [DocumentQuery.populate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html).

student schema

```
const schema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    courses: [{ type: mongoose.SchemaTypes.ObjectId, ref: 'Course' }]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Student', schema);
```

course schema

```
const schema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Course', schema);
```

test suite

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const mockgoose = new (require('mockgoose').Mockgoose)(mongoose);

const { assert, expect } = require('chai');

const Student = require('../models/student');
const Course = require('../models/course');

var student = null;

before(done => {
    mockgoose.prepareStorage().then(res => {
        mongoose.connect('mongodb://test/testDB', (err) => {
            if (err) {
                return done(err);
            }

            student = new Student({
                name: 'Shane'
            });

            student.save(err => {
                done(err);
            });
        });
    });
});

describe('population', () => {
    it('should populate referenced collection', done => {
        let course = new Course({
            name: 'Applied Sciences'
        });

        // save mock course
        course.save(err => {
            if (err) {
                return done(err);
            }

            student.courses.push(course._id);

            // push changes
            student.save(err => {
                if (err) {
                    return done(err);
                }

                // you can use any other find method that returns a DocumentQuery object
                Student.findOne({
                    name: 'Shane'
                }).populate('courses').exec((err, res) => {
                    if (err) {
                        return done(err);
                    }

                    expect(res.courses).to.have.lengthOf(1);

                    assert.equal(res.courses[0].name, 'Applied Sciences');

                    done();
                });
            });
        });
    });
});
```

When running the above using `mocha`, the assertions are passed and the student object is provided with one course.

Another thing to note is that `Schema.create` is used to push a batch of objects at once. It is debatable whether or not `doc.save` or `Schema.create` should be used. The create method actually only accepts an array of document but has a fallback for when one object is passed. It calls save on every document object and resolves when all documents are saved.

Comment: Thank you for this, I took a short course in mocha/chain not too long ago and sadly never continued using it for some reason. I'm still a beginner. The issue was actually something completely redundant. In my form I had set "name" to name="course[name]" but in my code I have req.body.name.....

Comment: @CollinDeSoto Something else I've noticed is that you push the object (`course`) rather then the ID reference to the students course collection. When you update one of the courses, the supposed courses of the student are not updated.

Comment: @CollinDeSoto This is what you set your reference type to (`mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId`) and requires you to call populate as displayed above. Otherwise no relation is made as mongo is not a relational database. In mongo there are not strict rules of what to push. You can even change to type of courses of the student object to be a string and it'll stringify and persist the student object to your database.

Comment: I see, within my app.get("/students",...) I have actually populated the Student.findById, I may have not updated that in the code above.

Comment: @CollinDeSoto What I meant to say is that you can push any document into a mongo collection. Right now, in your code, `student.courses` does not contain any relation to a persisted course. When you update one of the courses which one of the student holds, that object in `student.courses` *will not get updated*. This is because you pushed a document in to the array instead of the expected reference type `mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId`. I hope this clarifies the problem I am addressing. The above is how you do relational databases in mongo using mongoose.